# How the solve the equation in algebra in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var Solver = (function () {

    function Solver(equations) {
        this.params = Object.keys(equations)
        this.equations = this.parseEquations(equations)
    }
    
    Solver.prototype.parseEquations = function(equations){
        var replacements = {
            power : {
                re: /([\w.]+)\^([\w.]+)/g,
                res: 'Math.pow($1,$2)'
            },
            powerPython : {
                re: /([\w.]+)\*\*([\w.]+)/g,
                res: 'Math.pow($1,$2)'
            },
        }
        for(var key in equations){
            var eq = equations[key]
            for(var re in replacements){
                var repl = replacements[re]
                eq = eq.replace(repl.re, repl.res)
            }
            equations[key] = eq
        }
        return equations;
    }

    Solver.prototype.solve = function solve(obj) {
        var out = {},
            nullCount = Object.keys(this.equations).length,
            lastNull = 0;

        for (var key = 0; key < this.params.length; key++) {
            eval(this.params[key] + '=undefined')
        }

        for (var key in obj) {
            if (this.params.indexOf(key) != -1 && (obj[key]==0 || obj[key])) {
                eval(key + '=' + obj[key]),
                out[key] = obj[key]
            }
        }
        var equations = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.equations))
        while (lastNull !== nullCount) {
            lastNull = nullCount;
            for (var eq in equations) {
                with(Math)
                    var result = eval(equations[eq]);
                if (result) {
                    out[eq] = result;
                    equations[eq] = undefined;
                }
            }
            nullCount = Object.keys(equations).length;
        }
        return out;
    }

    return Solver;

}());

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') module.exports = Solver;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src='js-solver.js'></script>//declare the js library file

</head>
<body>
<div id="res"></div>
<script>
var triangleSolver = new Solver({
    area: 'base*h/2',
    c: 'Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a,2)+Math.pow(b,2)) || base/2', //base/2 is an example of a dual-equation definition
    a: 'Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c,2)-Math.pow(b,2))',
    b: 'Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c,2)-Math.pow(a,2))',
    h: 'area*2/base',
    base: 'area*2/h'
})
triangleSolver.solve({
    c: 5,
    b: 3,
    area: 50,
    h: 10
})
 document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = h;


</script>

</body>







</html>
```

I have some code in algebra in js-solver.I want to type the algebra equation in input field get the solution and steps for the equation but i try to use in algebra.js library but some long equation are not support so how to solve the equation please help me and correct my code. for example equation 1/4x2+5/4x = 3y - 12/5 how to solve .

Comment: please help how to use and solve the equation

Comment: based on the equation to draw the graph how its use

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a question about how to solve a math problem, and not a code issue.  (The op clearly indicates the js library doesn't support the equation, and is asking for help solving the equation).  Try math.stackexchange.com

Comment: please suggestion to any other solver library methods

Comment: hi any one can help to how to change the code in user type the equation based on draw the graph please help me